# Importing existing power desktop pbix file into workspace on Azure portal

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi

I am getting an error when I try to follow the steps to run PowerBI using the sample solution located in [PowerBI-CSharp](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/webforms/embed-a-report-into-an-app), when importing the PBIX Desktop file into my workspace on Azure (which is the second step and 6 item in the console provisioning app )

Error message does not say anything helpful: "Ooops, something broke: A task was canceled."

I tried with different PBIX files and even different workspaces in different times, no luck yet.

Currently I am using visual studio 2015 64 bit  (planning to try with VS 2013 in near future).

Comment: Sometimes the tool hides error messages.  Run fiddler or some othe HTTP tracing tool to see if the response returns any specific error information.

Comment: Have you tried with the sample file that is available to download in the getting started article?

Comment: Yes I have tried it several times no hope for that

Comment: @Serkan Demirhan, did you manage to solve this issue? I am receiving the very same error using the sample file. I even tried editing the file to make it smaller, as I thought the PostImportWithFileAsync task was timing out.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue while running the PowerBI sample solution. Any fix for this issue ?

Comment: After several try I downloaded and created simple basic pbix files to twstand worked for 5 tyr

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue.
I solved it by performing following steps:

1) creating simple .pbix file using Power BI desktop. 
2) Save it on your harddisk 
3) then try to upload it using console provisioning app.

Hope this will help!!

Answer (score 0):

I received similar kind of error with a message "file not found".
The issue occurs when we do not write ".pbix" extention with the file name.
For example:
if your power bi file has name "myproject" then while writing the file name in the "File name" option give name with extension as "myproject.pbix".

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue some time ago. Multiple things were going wrong.

First, the PBIX file I attempted to upload resided on a remote Hard Drive linked in my LAN network. The 'Getting-started' app did not have permissions to read the file. 
I fixed this by copying the PBIX file to my personal desktop.

Second, make sure to fill in the correct data required before-hand in the program. Edit the file `power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/ProvisionSample/App.config` to save your personal settings. This will give fast reproduction of running the code.

```
<!-- The Power BI API Endpoint -->
<add key="powerBiApiEndpoint" value="https://api.powerbi.com" />
<!-- The Azure Resource Manager API Endpoint-->
<add key="azureApiEndpoint" value="https://management.azure.com" />
<!-- Your Azure subscription ID -->
<add key="subscriptionId" value="" />
<!-- The Azure resource group name -->
<add key="resourceGroup" value="" />
<!-- The Power BI Workspace Collection Name -->
<add key="workspaceCollectionName" value="" />
<!-- The Power BI Workspace Collection Access Key -->
<add key="accessKey" value="" />
<!-- The Power BI Workspace-->
<add key="workspaceId" value="" />
<!-- Credentials to connect to datasource within Power BI -->
<add key="username" value="" />
<add key="password" value="" />
```

Note the last two values `username` and `password` are not required for uploading a PBIX file. All other values `subscriptionId`, `resourceGroup`, `workspaceCollectionName`, `accessKey` and `workspaceId` are a must. All this information can be found on the Azure cloud in the PowerBI workspace collection tile.

Third, make sure the `workspaceId` you are uploading to does not already contain a PBIX file. As far as I am concerned, it is not possible to replace a PBIX file on a workspace and therefore a new workspace must be created to upload the PBIX file to. Please correct me if I am wrong.